# Can't instantiate array of Generic type in Swift Language

Tags: swift

I'm trying to build a class that owns an array holding objects of generic type.  I have been unsuccessful so far.  Here is what I am doing:

```
class GenericTest<T>: NSObject {
    var objects = T[]()
}

var buffer = GenericTest<String>()
```

I get a segmentation fault when I do this as the program compiles, pre-run.  If I don't generalize, everything compiles without a problem

```
class NonGenericTest: NSObject {
    var objects = String[]()
}

var buffer = NonGenericTest()
```

This is not the approach I want to take though, as I have to solve this problem for a variety of types.  Any ideas why this is breaking?

Comment: Don't inherit from `NSObject`, use the `@objc` prefix on your `class` definition if you must have Obj-C compatibility. I have noticed that generics in Swift do not play nice with some of the old Obj-C constructs.

Comment: @SiLo I will mark this as correct if you put it as a response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, inheriting from `NSObject` is not a good idea when using generic classes in Swift.
I would say avoid doing so in *any* Swift class unless you absolutely must. If you need Obj-C compatibility then mark your class with the `@objc` prefix (along with any methods that will be called from Obj-C).

Silly but... yeah:

```
@objc class MyGeneric<T>
{
    var array = T[]()
}

var buffer = MyGeneric<String>()
```

You can use foundation classes like `NSString`, `NSDictionary`, and whatever else you want as a generic type parameter, but I would recommend against inheriting from `NSObject` in a generic class definition.